# Extract text with multiple regex patterns in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a list with address information

The placement of words in the list can be random.

```
address = [' South region', ' district KTS', ' 4', ' app. 106', ' ent. 1', ' st. 15']
```

I want to extract each item of a list in a new string.

```
r = re.compile(".region")

region = list(filter(r.match, address))
```

It works, but there are more than 1 pattern "region". For example, there can be "South reg." or "South r-n".
How can I combine a multiple patterns?
And digit 4 in list means building number. There can be onle didts, or smth like 4k1.
How can I extract building number?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully I understood the requirement correctly.
For extracting the region, I chose to get it by the first word, but if you can be sure of the regions which are accepted, it would be better to construct the regex based on the valid values, not first word.

Also, for the building extraction, I am not sure of which are the characters you want to keep, versus the ones which you may want to remove. In this case I chose to keep only alphanumeric, meaning that everything else would be stripped.

CODE

```
import re

list1 = [' South region', ' district KTS', ' -4k-1.', ' app. 106', ' ent. 1', ' st. 15'] 

def GetFirstWord(list2,column):
    return re.search(r'\w+', list2[column].strip()).group()

def KeepAlpha(list2,column):
    return re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+', '', list2[column].strip())

print(GetFirstWord(list1,0))

print(KeepAlpha(list1,2))
```

OUTPUT

```
South
4k1
```